# Increase of the rms during diffusion - Derivatives calculation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, derivatives, partial-derivative

We consider a diffusion equation of the form
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \!\cdot\! \left[ - \mathcal{F} (t , x) \right] \, 
$$
where ${ \mathcal{F} (t ,x) }$ is the *flux* vector of the diffusion. The initial conditions of the diffusion is given by
$$
F (x , t \!=\! 0) = F_{0} (x) \, .
$$
I am interested in the evolution of the rms of the function $F$ during diffusion. As a consequence, I naturally introduce the well-defined function $g$ as
$$
g (t) = \sqrt{\int \!\! \mathrm{d} x \, \left[ F (x , t) \!-\! F_{0} (x) \right]^{2}} \, .
$$
One can note that ${ g (t \!=\! 0) \!=\! 0 }$. I am interested in the behavior of $g$ for small times, so that I introduce the limited development
$$
g(t) \simeq g_{0} \!+\! g_{1} t \!+\! g_{2} \frac{t^{2}}{2} \!+\! ... \, , 
$$
where we have
$$
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle g_{0} = g (t \!=\! 0) \, ,
\\
\displaystyle g_{1} = \frac{\mathrm{d} g}{\mathrm{d} t} \bigg|_{t = 0} \, ,
\\
\displaystyle g_{2} = \frac{\mathrm{d}^{2} g}{\mathrm{d} t^{2}} \bigg|_{t = 0} \, .
\end{cases}
$$
To compute the coefficient $g_{1}$, I naively applied the chain rule and the derivation under the integral sign to write
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} g}{\mathrm{d} t} = \frac{\displaystyle \int \!\! \mathrm{d} x \, \left[ F (x , t) \!-\! F_{0} (x) \right] \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}}{\displaystyle  \sqrt{\int \!\! \mathrm{d} x \, \left[ F (x , t) \!-\! F_{0} (x) \right]^{2}}} \, .
$$
However, one should note that this expression when evaluated in ${ t \!=\! 0 }$ is ill-defined, since it takes the form ${ \sim 0 / 0 }$. However, the coefficient $g_{1}$ should be a perfectly well-defined function, since the function $g$ is a perfectly regular function.

How should one proceed to write a *correct* expression for $g_{1}$ ?

(Additional question : I have the same issue with $g_{2}$ that I also need to evaluate...)

Comment: Maybe you could just consider $\bar{g}:=g^2$ obtain the series and then return back to $g$.

Comment: @CTNT Yes indeed ! Your suggestion is exactly the simple idea I had missed. With your notations, one obtains : $\bar{g}_{0} \!=\! 0$, $\bar{g}_{1} \!=\! 0$, $\bar{g}_{2} \!>\! 0$, so that $g_{1} \!=\! \sqrt{\bar{g}_{2} / 2} $.